# Alternative methods to determine A-320 (Pegasus R1A) Optimal FL

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus, fms, automation

320 FO looking to see if anyone knows a method to determine optimal flight level (essentially compute optimal step climb *point*) from the F-PLN page. I’m well aware of computing optimal S/C from the STEP ALTS page, but I remember long ago a line check airman dropping some code into the right side of the F-PLN page. Curious if anyone can find any information on this shortcut.